# How to achieve this CSS layout?

Tags: css, layout

I'm not very good at describing this issue in words, so i painted a small picture with the properties the layout should have.

[image]

I tried several possibilities but i wasn't able to achieve this without absolute positioning and flexboxes. I'm also not so familiar with css hacks.

Does anybody have a solution for this type of layout with CSS only and IE9+ (if possible IE8) compatibility?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? What problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: There are many possibilities to create this layout, however you need to show us what you tried. We're not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, good luck bro and welcome to the world of front end.

[Solution Here](http://codepen.io/loruit/pen/WrNEer)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id = "content">
            <div class="sidenav"></div>
            <div class="info"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    background: navy;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: pink;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 4em; /*same height header*/
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 4em;
    /* or:
    padding: 4em 0 4em 0;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
   */
}

.sidenav {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.info {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.

HTML

```
<header>
</header>

<section>

  <aside>
  </aside>

  <article>
  </article>

</section>

<footer>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer,
header {
  width: 100%;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
}
section:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
aside {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
article {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
```

[Here is an example](http://codepen.io/taniarascia/pen/YwzQbd)

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I took Gilberto's anwser because it leaves the sidenav flexible without specifying width in % and doesn't use tables for alignment.